# Converting HTML to PDF exact replica not shown

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am doing an R&D for converting HTML to PDF. 
We have created a page in Asp.net and has placed a CKEditor on it with simple options of selecting Fonts, Font Size, Bond, Italic etc. There is two more text boxes from where user can enter height and width of PDF to be generated. In addition to this we have div which shows preview of the content on the basis of text inserted in Editor. The Div height and width are set at run time, basically with this div we want to show how pdf is going to look like.
We are using wkhtmltopdf exe for generating PDF.

Now my problem is that the PDF being created is not exact replica of content shown in Div, sometimes it show exact content line by line but some times some words move out to next line in PDF

We have tried lot and lot of things to achieve exact result but could not successes any help is appriciable.

Comment: I've held back waiting for somebody else to offer a positive response, but... All I can offer is to say that frankly I'm surprised it works as well as it does. Having two different rendering engines (one in ASP.NET, the other in wkhtmltopdf) treat fonts (kerning, anti-aliasing, hinting, etc.) and word wrap _exactly_ the same way doesn't seem likely to me. Can you modify your app's UI to reset your users' expectations to what you can actually deliver  ...rather than something that doesn't quite work? (Maybe "greek" the text in the preview?)

Comment: To add to what Chuck Kollars commented, the output from CKEditor can vary from browser to browser as they too tend to render things differently from one to another. Even different PDF readers sometimes have differnet outputs on the same screen. Then there are different PDF printing drivers etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is using DOMPDF:
https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

It's updated pretty frequently and has always given me great results.

Another suggestion would be to create styles specific to the PDF to get the desired result and then have those applied when the PDF is created.

In otherwords if you have a button "generate pdf" have it take all HTML content and then insert PDF specific style tags that you've tested in your PDF generator that makes the rendering the same as the browser. You could do this by just replacing:

```
</head>
```

With

```
<style>STYLES SPECIFIC TO PDF</style>
</head>
```

Upon creation of the PDF.

PDF rendering in my experience usually requires a few extra rules to make it look like web rending engines.

Hope that helps.